# Xcode: Missing arm64 Symbols from MagTek iOS Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am having an issue adding the MagTek library and header. After they are added (I followed all the information I could find) I get this error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTSCRA", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CONAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have wasted so much time figuring this out. I am using Xcode 5. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MagTek library must not 64-bit and you are trying to run against the iPhone 64-bit simulator and/or on the iPhone 5s. In your "Build Settings," under "Architectures," try changing to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` or `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` to not build the 64-bit version as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with following changes ( In your "Build Settings," under "Architectures"),

1. Removed arm64 from the list of 'Valid Architectures'
2. 'Build Active Architecture Only' set to 'No'
3. Set architectures to 'Standard Architectures'

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11 onwards all apps should be in 64-bit, so you can get the latest iOS MagTek library at..

https://www.magtek.com/support/idynamo?tab=software

Comment: In the latest version of the SDK available at the link above, even the demos do not work in the simulator, and only one binary is provided. Is there any way to get the most recent version running in the simulator?